# Power BI dashboard with real time streaming data present in Amazon Aurora

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, mysql-connector, amazon-aurora, real-time-data

I am new to powerBI and have a powerBI pro account, I would like to know how can I use the data present in Aurora RDS to create real-time dashboards in Power BI with a 30-sec refresh cadence. I thought of connecting the data to powerBI using MYSQL connector but just figured that MYSQL database connection in powerBI does not support directQuery. Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try the following approach:

1. In Power BI there is an option to use a push url as data source. The concept is that data can be pushed into the Power BI dashboard via this url.
2. Then, in AWS use a service like for example AWS Lambda that will query the Aurora RDS every 30 seconds and invoke the Power BI push url.

Comment: would you recommend changing the viz tool to tableau? will it make the integration easier?

Comment: If tableu supports real time data via push url or another similar approach then it is worth exploring. Also check the pricing, it seems to be cheaper in Power BI with $10 per user for the PRO license. And Power BI desktop version is free.

Comment: Another alternative is to not use any BI tool. Create your own custom web application containing a javascript charting tool. Code the web app to query and fetch the AWS RDS data every 30 seconds and display the data by passing it to the JavaScript chart. See https://www.chartjs.org/